# Is it generally preferred that empty products are gotten rid of where possible?

Tags: soft-question, notation, products

Is it generally preferred that empty products are gotten rid of where possible?

For example:

Stewart's structure theorem says that for a positive integer $n$, every positive integer $\leq n$ has a representation as a sum of distinct divisors of $n$ iff (if and only if) $n=1$, or $p_1=2$ and $p_i-1\leq\sigma(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}})$ for every $i\in[2,\omega(n)]$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$. Such numbers are called practical numbers. However, we don't have to state $p_1=2$ if we require the special case with $i=1$ to hold, from which $$p_1-1\leq\sigma(\prod_{j=1}^{0}p_j^{a_j})=\sigma(1)=1,$$ thus $p_1=2$, since $1$ is not prime.

But there are other ways to get rid of the empty product than by stating $p_1=2$ explicitly; Multiplying both sides by $\sigma(p_i^{a_i})$ results in

$$p_i^{a_i+1}-1\leq\sigma(\prod_{j=1}^{i}p_j^{a_j})$$

so that for $i=1,\hspace{1mm}p_1^{a_1+1}-1\leq\dfrac{p_1^{a_1+1}-1}{p_1-1}\implies p_1\leq 2\implies p_1=2$.

Another option in this case is to define a function $T_i(n)$ which returns these "truncations" of the prime factorization of $n$ (that appear in the divisor sum) so that $T_0(n)=1$ and $T_{\omega(n)}(n)=n$. In order to avoid having an empty product in the definition of this function we might define the functions $p_i(n)$ to return $1$ and $a_i(n)$ to return $0$ whenever $i\not\in[1,\omega(n)]$, then let $$T_i(n)=\prod_{j=0}^i p_j(n)^{a_j(n)}$$

Comment: Why would you want to eliminate empty products? They're not particularly ugly.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think they are either, but I thought that in some contexts there might be "more rigorous" ways to state the same thing. The main reason I'm interested is because I would think that the most "natural" definition of a sequence is most likely to have a form similar to that of a generalization of that sequence. I thought that for some notations at least like $p_1p_2...p_{i-1}$ it might be frowned upon to include the case $i=1$ without defining $p_0$ or perhaps stating that for that case you take the empty product.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. As long as you're dealing with a numerical product (or even an operation in a semigroup with identity), defining an empty product to be the identity works out extremely nicely. If you're dealing with more general sorts of products (e.g., Cartesian products, topological products, etc.), you end up having to give up equality and settle for isomorphism in *general* (e.g., $A\times(B\times C)\cong (A\times B)\times C$ but equality does not hold), so the fact that there's no *real* identity doesn't seem like such a big deal.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Is it usual to explicitly state that the the lack of terms in the product is the multiplicative identity  or is reasonable to expect this to be assumed by the reader? Perhaps you could put this as an answer. Otherwise, I'll probably just delete the question after your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're dealing with a numerical product (or even an operation in a semigroup with identity), defining an empty product to be the identity works out extremely nicely. If you're dealing with more general/weirder sorts of "products" (e.g., Cartesian products, topological products, etc.), you end up having to give up equality and settle for isomorphism in general (e.g., $A\times(B\times C)\cong(A\times B)\times C$ but equality does not hold), so the fact that there's no real identity doesn't seem like such a big deal.

The reason the empty product being the multiplicative identity makes sense is, very simply, that it works nicely with the general rule that
$$\prod_{i\in I_1}x_i\cdot \prod_{i\in I_2}x_i=\prod_{i\in I_1\sqcup I_2}x_i.$$

Comment: Great, thank you. To restate my final question, is it fine to define the practical numbers for instance as $n=1$, or $n>1$ such that $p_i\leq 1+\sigma(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}})$ for every $i\in[1,\omega(n)]$, where $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_{\omega(n)}^{a_{\omega(n)}}$ is the canonical prime factorization of $n$, without stating explicitly that the empty product is to be taken as the identity?

Comment: @JaycobColeman, I have no idea. I'm way too tired to puzzle that out. Sorry.

Comment: All I'm asking is whether it is always assumed that a product without any terms is the identity or if it should be explicitly stated. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @JaycobColeman, if there is an identity, then yes, absolutely. I don't believe there is any possibility of confusion whatsoever.